# 2SLS with 2 exogenous variables in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I am experimenting with my 2SLS model and believe I have two exogenous variables. I think I can do the two stages of 2SLS manually, but would prefer to use an R function if that is available. I use ivreg now; is there a similar function with an option to instrument more than one variable?

Comment: You're right in better using a function designed for that, since it should calculate the variance correctly. You may want to try [`lfe::felm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lfe/index.html).